# Polar chart x axis 0 placement

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I have a polar chart I created by MSChart control in my WinForms app. X axis type is date, y is integer. X represents exactly one day.

My problem is that I can not set date 00:00 to the place I need, it always appears at various places.

Here is the chart I create:
[image]

00 is highlighted by red. I'd like to move it where now 14:00 can be found (highlighted by blue).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've got it by myself:

```
chartMain.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Crossing = 270;
```